# return a shifted element from an array element js

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, shift

I need to return the next person in line by name.  I tried other versions and at one point it returned a number but not the string.  Apologies, new for now, but will be great one day.

```
 function nowServing(){
  if (katzDeli.length > 0) {
      return `Currently serving ${katzDeli.shift()}`;
        } else {
    return `There is nobody waiting to be served!`;
  }
  }
```

The above is skipping the "if" and executing the "else."  If the array is empty I need it to return the else string.
-update-
It throws the following error:
 deli nowServing returns an announcement about the person it is serving, and shifts the line:

```
  Error: Expected 'There is nobody waiting to be served!' to equal 'Currently serving Steven.'                                                   
  + expected - actual                                                                                                                            

  -There is nobody waiting to be served!                                                                                                         
  +Currently serving Steven.
```

It is in an IDE for a course I'm in.  So I don't enter the values for the array.  As it reads (the error) it says that there isn't anyone in the line.  Also, an aside, how can I avoid downvotes?  I seem to get one everytime I ask a question.
Thanks

Comment: it is working fine. what is the problem with it?

Comment: can you put an example for your array ?

Comment: it looks like a problem with your ide. you could use a variable for the shifted element and try that.

Answer (score 0):

When I try the code, it works fine:

```
function nowServing(){
  if (katzDeli.length > 0) {
    return `Currently serving ${katzDeli.shift()}`;
  } else {
    return `There is nobody waiting to be served!`;
  }
}

var katzDeli = ['foo', 'bar'];
console.log(nowServing()) // Currently serving foo
console.log(nowServing()) // Currently serving bar
console.log(nowServing()) // There is nobody waiting to be served!
console.log(nowServing()) // There is nobody waiting to be served!
```

---

If and when you do update your question, I will also update the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'd have another suggestion. Array.prototype.shift() will return undefined if there are no elements left.

```
function nowServing() {
    var customer = katzDeli.shift();
    return `Currently serving ${customer ? customer : "nobody" }`;
}
```